# UDP socket fail to receive ECONNREFUSED

Tags: c, udp, winsock, icmp

I created a socket using: socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP).

According to [this](http://www.wlug.org.nz/ECONNREFUSED), if I send simple packet several times (multiply send() and/or sendto()), I can get ECONNREFUSED. ICMP should tell that previous packet didn't arrive and ECONNREFUSED should appear. But it fails, errno doesn't report about any errors, and send() always returns number of bytes sent.

UDP protocol actually shouldn't tell that packet was sent. But ICMP can give advice as I understand.

So, the question is - why does it fail to receive ECONNREFUSED?

Everything is done using Winsock.

Comment: Did you call connect() on your UDP socket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two reasons for this.

- The target machine does not (for some reason) send the `ICMP` back
- The target machines *does* send the `ICMP` back but `winsock` doesn't correctly interpret it (I know that certain older Unixes did this)

In short, your best bet to find out would be using a sniffer. Try wireshark and see if you get an ICMP back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. System is winxp, local machine. ICMP is just assumption, probably something else

Answer (score 1):

[INFO: Winsock Ignores ICMP Port Unreachable Control Messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245442)

You have to enable the `SIO_UDP_CONNRESET` control via `WSAIoctl()` in order for UDP sockets to react to ICMP failures:

[WinSock Recvfrom() now returns WSAECONNRESET instead of blocking or timing out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263823/EN-US)